# Appending two NSMutableDictionary - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, object, key, nsmutabledictionary

I have two NSMutableDictionary objects of the below format:

```
{products = {  sitedetails =   { currency = USD; };}
```

and this :

```
 {products =    { sitedetails =   { latestoffers =   { price =  { test = { gte = 100; };  }; };  }; };  }
```

and i need to append to a format that looks something like this:

```
{products =    { sitedetails =   { { currency = USD; },latestoffers =   { price =  { test = { gte = 100; };  }; };  }; };  }
```

I have to append them in such a way that the objects of sitedetails for both the nsmutabedictionaries are added as single dictionary.

## possible objects and keys

```
 [sem queryBuilderWithObj:@"4992" andKeyValue:@"cat_id" ];
 [sem queryBuilderWithObj:@"Toshiba" andKeyValue:@"brand"];
 [sem queryBuilderWithObj:@"1000000" andKeyValue:@"weight,gte"];
 [sem queryBuilderWithObj:@"1500000" andKeyValue:@"weight,lt"];
 [sem queryBuilderWithObj:@"newegg.com"andKeyValue:@"sitedetails,name" ];
 [sem queryBuilderWithObj:@"USD" andKeyValue:@"sitedetails,latestoffers,currency"];
 [sem queryBuilderWithObj:@"100" andKeyValue:@"sitedetails,latestoffers,price,gte"];
```

Its not fixed but that  is just a sample.

Comment: Can there possibly be other values in the dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the two dictionaries you have be dict1 and dict2

```
NSMutableDictionary* product1 = [dict1 objectForKey: @"products"];  //dict1 = {products = {  sitedetails =   { currency = USD; };}

NSMutableDictionary* product2 = [dict2 objectForKey: @"products"];   //dict2 = {products =    { sitedetails =   { latestoffers =   { price =  { test = { gte = 100; };  }; };  }; };  }

NSMutableDictionary* product1_sidetails = [product1 objectForKey: @"sidetails"];

NSMutableDictionary* product2_sidetails = [product2 objectForKey: @"sidetails"];

[product1_sidetails addEntriesFromDictionary:product2_sidetails ];

NSMutableDictionary* products = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[products setObject: product1_sidetails forKey: @"sidetails"];

NSMutableDictionary* finalProducts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[finalProducts setObject:products forKey:@"products"];

//finalProducts will be your final dictionary
```

Comment: [product1 objectForKey: @"sidetails"] => you are trying to access the object (a dictionary with key sitedetails) Initial key is product

Comment: @downvote could you please mention the reason. Isn't the code working?

Comment: It works fine. Thank you and yes I didn't down vote ur answer

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan No issues, i just wanted to know if the code is working. Thanks :)